# Java Actionlisteners error

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jmenuitem

I have been trying for quite a while now and i cant figure out what the problem is. Im using actionlisteners on my JmenuItems but when i start the program and click the button i get errors which i cant understand why? Any help is appreciated.

code for the button im using:

```
final JMenuItem Start = new JMenuItem("Start");
    Start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if(e.getSource() == Start) {
            pane.GuessBox.setEditable(true);

         }

        }

    });
```

The errors im recieving:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Main$1.actionPerformed(Main.java:37)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

GuessBox:

```
JTextField GuessBox = new JTextField(1);

    GuessBox.setEditable(false);
    GuessBox.addActionListener(new Command());
    GuessPanel.add(GuessBox);
```

Comment: which is line no 37 in Main.java?

Comment: Pane.Guessbox.setEditable(true);

Comment: What is `pane`? What is `pane.GuessBox`? I can assure you that one of them is **null**

Comment: I think pane is null.

Comment: Im using Pane which is another class file and grabbing the guessbox textfield from it.

Comment: Have you created object of `Pane pane = new Pane();` or just used `Pane pane;`

Comment: i did, Pane pane  = new Pane();

Comment: Please read about [What is a NullPointerException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception/218390#218390)

Comment: `Follow Java naming conventions`. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character! "Start" should be "start"...

Comment: Quit guessing. Which variable is null, "pane" or "guessBox"? All you need to do us use System.out.println(...) to print both variable to determine which is null. Then you solve your problem. We can't help because we don't have your code. Just make sure you haven't defined your variable twice, once as an instance variable and once as a local variable.

Comment: @camickr - `Start`, is set final. So it should really be `START` instead.

Comment: @RudiKershaw, didn't notice the "final". But there is no need for it to be final. It was only done that way because the ActionListener was not implement properly. There is no need to check if the button is the start button because an anonymous inner class is being used. So I would suggest the ActionListener code should be changed.

Comment: I found the problem i had two of the same variables one instantiated and one who wasn't instantiated, and the program was referring to the one not instantiated so the problem is fixed.

Comment: @RudiKershaw All capitalized letters should only be used for **static final** (what we in Java could call "constants"). The JMenuItem here is not a static final and should therefore be called `start` according to the naming conventions.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg - Do you have a source for that? Although I can't find any specifications in the official Oracle/JavaBeans docs, using caps for non-static finals seems in wide use.

Comment: @RudiKershaw [The official Oracle code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java) :)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg - My bad, I seem to miss the obvious fairly regularly. I do wonder though what they meant by "class constants and of ANSI constants". Comparing ANSI constants to class constants implies that ANSI might not be 'class' constants.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your problem is probably here.

`pane.GuessBox.setEditable(true);`

If `GuessBox` (or `pane`) is not instantiated (or set null), then setEditable can not be called on null.

Comment: **not instantiated** and **being null** are two separate things. Otherwise you are correct.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg- Yea, that's true. I'll change 'ie' for 'eg' or like. Thanks :)